# How can I find out that a publication has "replicated schema changes" enabled?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication, merge-replication

Where can I find out (preferably using T-SQL) within a published databases, if it would replicate the schema changes?

[here is how to create a publication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms151160(v=sql.120).aspx)

This topic describes how to create a publication in SQL Server 2014 by using SQL Server Management Studio, Transact-SQL, or Replication Management Objects (RMO).

[Replicate Schema Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms152562(v=sql.120).aspx#TsqlProcedure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this stored procedure at the Publisher:

```
sp_helpmergepublication
```

And check this column:

```
replicate_ddl
```

A value of 1 means that schema changes are replicated

Comment: You beat me to it!  For a Transactional Publication use sp_helppublication and check replicate_ddl.